# Joomla Tags Url problem

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I have created tags module as well as menu item

But if i insert tags in articles, url gets website.com/component/tags/tag/1-abc

How can we remove component/tags and convert links from website.com/component/tags/tag to website.com/tag/1-abc

I am using Joomla! 3.4.3 Stable

Answer (score 2):

The only native workaround I know is to create new menu items to all tags you have (you could put them inside a hidden menu if you want to). This will make all tag links on your website will be having the same url.

Comment: I just created Tag menu item in hidden menu. But I am putting multiple tags in articles and it will be really painful to create menu item for each tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Joomla Rewriting and .htaccess file:

- System >> Global Configuration >> Use URL Rewriting YES;
- Rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess in your root folder;

Implement in your .htaccess file one rule like this:

```
## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^component/(.*)$ $1
```

You can see complete explanation how rewrite works here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Thank you Max: One more question is raised that if i add rewrite rule in htaccess, will google index both urls? with Components/tags/tag/ and without component in url?

Comment: I think, by logic, the rewrite rule override any external access. Only your server know real path.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using K2 for blogging and tagging, but if you don't want to go that route then Webchun answer would have my vote.